# How to create new variables based on multiple conditions on existing variable values

Tags: r, dataframe, if-statement, na

I have a dataframe with 3 variables:

```
 P1 P2 P3 
  2 12  8 
  2  1  6 
  2  7  8 
 NA NA  2 
  1 NA  6 
 NA  8 11
```

I need to calculate the values ​​for 5 other new variables based on the following conditions:

```
P1<-c(2,2,2,NA,1,NA)
P2<-c(12,1,7,NA,NA,8)
P3<-c(8,6,8,2,6,11)

df<-data.frame(P1,P2,P3)
attach(df)

X1<-X2<-X3<-X4<-X5<-c()

for(i in 1:(dim(df)[1])){
  #X1
  if((P3[i]==1||P3[i]==2||P3[i]==4||P3[i]==5||P3[i]==7||P3[i]==13) || ((P3[i]==3||P3[i]==6||P3[i]==8||P3[i]==12)&&(P1[i]==1))){X1[i]<-1
  }else{X1[i]<-0}
  
  #X2
  if((P3[i]==3||P3[i]==6||P3[i]==8||P3[i]==11||P3[i]==12)&&
     (P2[i]==1||P2[i]==2||P2[i]==3||P2[i]==5||P2[i]==6||P2[i]==7||P2[i]==10||P2[i]==11)){X2[i]<-1
  }else{X2[i]<-0}
  
  #X3
  if(P3[i]==1||P3[i]==2||P3[i]==4||P3[i]==5||P3[i]==7||P3[i]==13){X3<-1
  }else{X3[i]<-0}
  
  #X4
  if((P3[i]==3||P3[i]==6||P3[i]==8||P3[i]==12)&&(P1[i]==1)){X4<-1
  }else{X4[i]<-0}
  
  #X5
  if((P3[i]==6||P3[i]==8||P3[i]==11) && (P2[i]=12||P2[i]==8)){X5[i]<-1
  }else{X5[i]<-0}
}
df<-cbind(df,X1,X2,X3,X4,X5)
```

This is the result I want:

```
 P1 P2 P3 X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 
  2 12  8  0  0  0  0  1 
  2  1  6  0  1  0  0  0 
  2  7  8  0  1  0  0  0 
 NA NA  2  1  0  1  0  0 
  1 NA  6  1  0  0  1  0 
 NA  8 11  0  0  0  0  1
```

But instead of getting it, I get the following error:

> Error in if ((P3[i] == 3 || P3[i] == 6 || P3[i] == 8 || P3[i] == 11 ||  :
> missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

I am aware that I have a problem with NAs, as when I remove observations with NA, I don't get that error, but as much as I try different methods, I can't find any way to fix it.

On the other hand, there is an error in the result when I run the rows without NA.

```
P1<-c( 2,2,2)
P2<-c(12,1,7)  #rows without NA
P3<-c( 8,6,8)
```

```
 P1 P2 P3 X1 X2 X3 X4 X5
  2 12  8  0  0  0  0  1
  2  1  6  0  1  0  0  1
  2  7  8  0  1  0  0  1
```

I get the above result while I should get this:

```
 P1 P2 P3 X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 
  2 12  8  0  0  0  0  1 
  2  1  6  0  1  0  0  0 
  2  7  8  0  1  0  0  0
```

Could someone help me fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what changed and why:

1. In X2 and X5 condition I added `!is.na(P2[i]) &&`  before actual check for P2 to first make sure that we are not dealing with `NA`. If this statement result in false then we are sure that else statement should be executed.
2. In X3 and X4 you had `X3<-1` instead of `X3[i]<-1`
3. In X5 condition there was `P2[i]=12||P2[i]==8` - first single equality sign then double equality sign. Single equality sign is for assignment therefore it resulted in TRUE value and was causing problems that you described in the second part of your question.

And here is working code:

```
P1<-c(2, 2,2,NA,1,NA)
P2<-c(12,1,7,NA,NA,8)
P3<-c(8, 6,8, 2,6,11)

df<-data.frame(P1,P2,P3)
attach(df)

X1<-X2<-X3<-X4<-X5<-c()

for(i in 1:(dim(df)[1])){
  #X1
  if((P3[i]==1 || P3[i]==2 || P3[i]==4 || P3[i]==5 || P3[i]==7 || P3[i]==13) || ((P3[i]==3 || P3[i]==6 || P3[i]==8 || P3[i]==12) && (P1[i]==1))){
    X1[i]<-1
  }else{
    X1[i]<-0
  }
  #X2
  if((P3[i]==3 || P3[i]==6 || P3[i]==8 || P3[i]==11 || P3[i]==12) && (!is.na(P2[i]) && (P2[i]==1 || P2[i]==2 || P2[i]==3 || P2[i]==5 || P2[i]==6 || P2[i]==7 || P2[i]==10 || P2[i]==11))){
    X2[i]<-1
  }else{
    X2[i]<-0
  }
  #X3
  if(P3[i]==1 || P3[i]==2 || P3[i]==4 || P3[i]==5 || P3[i]==7 || P3[i]==13){
    X3[i]<-1
  }else{
    X3[i]<-0
  }
  #X4
  if((P3[i]==3 || P3[i]==6 || P3[i]==8 || P3[i]==12)&&(P1[i]==1)){
    X4[i]<-1
  }else{
    X4[i]<-0
  }
  #X5
  if((P3[i]==6 || P3[i]==8 || P3[i]==11) && (!is.na(P2[i]) && (P2[i] == 12 || P2[i] == 8))){
    X5[i]<-1
  }else{
    X5[i]<-0
  }
}
df<-cbind(df,X1,X2,X3,X4,X5) 
show(df)
```